# Using mapply to plot

Tags: r, mapply

I'm trying to iteratively plot scatterplots ONLY using `mapply`. 
Let's say I have the `iris` dataset:

```
> names(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length"
[4] "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

I would like to use `mapply()` and only `mapply()` to plot `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, and `Petal.Width` against `Sepal.Length`

I have this starter code:

```
    mapply(function(ii){plot(x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
           y = ii, ylab = paste(names(ii)), xlab = "Sepal Length")},
           ii = iris[c(2,3,4)])
```

Everything works fine here EXCEPT the y axis labels. I want it to display the column names of the y-axis values, but this does not work.

Comment: Since you're only iterating over one variable, you can use `lapply`. One approach is to paste together formulas, so `lapply(paste(names(iris[2:4]), '~', names(iris)[1]), function(x) plot(as.formula(x), data = iris))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider passing column names to fit your column assignment and *ylab* character requirement. And as @alistaire comments, you are only passing one vector into your function. Mapply (informally as **m**ultivariate **apply**) is designed to iterate elementwise through more than one equal-length or multiple-length vectors. This would be akin to passing in *Sepal.Length* 1 or 3 times:

```
plotfct <- function(ii, jj)
  plot(x = iris[[ii]], y = iris[[jj]], 
       xlab = paste(ii), ylab = paste(ii))

mapply(plotfct, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Length"), 
                c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))
```

But since *Sepal.Length* does not change, repeating its value to meet the length of longer is redundant. Simply use `lapply` or its simplified wrapper, `sapply`:

```
plotfct <- function(ii)
  plot(x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]], y = iris[[ii]], 
       xlab = "Sepal Length", ylab = paste(ii))

lapply(c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), plotfct)

# EQUIVALENTLY:
# sapply(c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), plotfct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither `mapply` nor `lapply` pass the names of the items in their data objects to the "working functions". What you see after the function completion is that they add back the names to the results. Even if you use the deparse(substitute)) strategy you end up with a useless name like "dots[[1L]][[1L]]". So you are condemned to either index by the names themselves or by a numeric index into the `names(dataframe)` values.